# How to Redirect a Python Console output to a QTextBox

Tags: python, console, qwidget, redirect

I'm working on developing a GUI for the recompilation of Linux kernel. For this I need to implement 4-5 Linux commands from Python. I use Qt as GUI designer.  I have successfully implemented the commands using `os.system()` call. But the output is obtained at the console.  The real problem is the output of command is a listing that takes almost 20-25 min continuous printing. How we can transfer this console output to a text box designed in Qt.  Can any one help me to implement the `setSource()` operation in Qt using source as the live console outputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
self.process = QProcess()
self.connect(self.process, SIGNAL("readyReadStdout()"), self.readOutput)
self.connect(self.process, SIGNAL("readyReadStderr()"), self.readErrors)
tarsourcepath="sudo tar xvpf "+ self.path1
self.process.setArguments(QStringList.split(" ",tarsourcepath))
self.process.start()



def readOutput(self):

    self.textBrowser2.append(QString(self.process.readStdout()))
    if self.process.isRunning()==False:
        self.textBrowser2.append("\n Completed Successfully")




def readErrors(self):
    self.textBrowser2.append("error: " + QString(self.process.readLineStderr()))
```

This did the work quite good for me. thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly deal with wxPython, but is http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Capturing_Output_from_a_Process a solution that would work?

From the page:

> **Problem:** You want to run a process
>   that prints lots of information to the
>   console and display the output in a
>   text editor or browser, but the result
>   is a GUI that freezes until the
>   process is finished.
>
> **Solution (one of many possible):**
>   Create a QProcess object, connect its
>   signals to some slots in your class,
>   pass it the required arguments and
>   start it. Data on the process's stdout
>   and stderr is delivered to your slots.
>
> [continued...](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Capturing_Output_from_a_Process)

Comment: Great help Bro, it really have something for me.but wat i got is about windows only.i need to make system calls using it.ie its about executing some programs with req arguments.but it was great help bro as i could get the way to implement the application interface. Thanks

Comment: again tried and got it successfully done bro. I used start() unstead of closeStdin() it workd smoothly.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a pipe comes to mind. You could use a background thread that reads the output of the program (and sends events to the GUI whenever a new line is added).

So the basic idea is this:

```
os.chdir("/usr/src/linux-2.6.34")

p = os.popen("make", "r")
try:
    while True:
        line = p.readline()
        if not line:
            break

        # Replace this with a GUI update event (don't know anything about Qt, sorry)
        print line
finally:
    # Cf. http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen
    programReturnValue = p.close() or 0
```

Comment: the idea is good bro, but the problem is i dot kno if the thread is able to transfer what is on out out till now. because i dont think we have enuf time diffrence for updation. But i could find the answer from above answer by NIck. Thanks for helping me andiDog.